# Reset cache in AWS Lambda when AWS Secrets Manager secret value is updated

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am using AWS Secrets Manager for storing secrets and use it in one of my AWS Lambda functions. AWS also provides `AWSSDK.SecretsManager.Caching` library to improve performance and reduce costs. I also start using it with a long caching lifetime (1 day).

The next step is, when the secret value will be changed, I need to reset the cache immediately.

Now, my question is, how can Lambda be notified that it needs to reset the cache?

Answer (score 1):

This can be tricky with serverless functions.

If the rotation time is predicable then store the expiration time of the secret along with the secret as a pair, then the Lambda function can discard and re-fetch the secret as needed when it's expired.

If key rotation happens at arbitrary times, then either:

1. enhance the Lambda function to deal with the consequences of having a bad secret value (e.g. a DB connection might fail triggering the Lambda function to re-fetch the secret and retry the connection)
2. maintain some kind of state e.g. in DynamoDB that's efficient to update when a secret is rotated so that the Lambda function can query this state any time it's about to use the cached secret